# Dragonfly, rails 3.2, Refinery Edge (2.0) ImageMagick on Centos 5.6

Tags: imagemagick, centos, ruby-on-rails-3.2, refinerycms, dragonfly-gem

I have all the dependancies installed (or I think I do). I definitely have ImageMagick installed, however when using Refinery(v2.9 on rails 3.2) to upload images, I get the following error:

NoMethodError (undefined method `downcase' for nil:NilClass):
  dragonfly (0.9.10) lib/dragonfly/image_magick/utils.rb:26:in`identify'
....

I found this similar question but totally baffled where to place this code:
[Dragonfly Gem with ImageMagick and Passenger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6008183/dragonfly-gem-with-imagemagick-and-passenger)

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

M.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you reinstall ruby 1.9.3 and Imagemagick. Usually this error occurs for not having Imagemagick installed, as the identity class is located there.

Comment: yes you are some what right, I did not have the latest or a more recent version of ImageMagick which is such an annoyance to install ... but is possible with perseverance.